# Can a Java Thread be safely stopped by return-ing inside the run() method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that Thread.stop() and other functions are deprecated, and I want to stop a thread from running if a certain condition is met. Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing now:

```
public class SomeThread extends Thread
{
    private static boolean running = true;

    public static void shutdown()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while( running )
        {
            // do something cool
        }

        return; // <- this is what I'm wondering about
    }
}
```

When another class calls SomeThread's shutdown() method, the while loop exits, and then the run() method returns. Is this safe?

The main reason I'm using a while loop instead of just letting run() do the work is because there are a few things I only want to do once (before the while loop), and I'm really only using the thread for concurrency. I'm sure this is a bastardization of what Threads were meant for, but I'm mainly just wondering about the return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return is fine, the rest of your code is iffy.

The `running` member should either be volatile, or you need some synchronization around the reads and writes to that variable.

(Having `shutdown` and `running` as statics is unusual.)

Comment: I am actually doing synchronization right now (although the code above doesn't reflect that), but would removing the statics and changing "running" to volatile be enough to keep it thread safe?

(I'm trying to remember exactly why I used static in this context. I don't believe it's needed now that you've pointed it out.)

Comment: If you have proper synchronization, don't remove it in favor of volatile. It's (in my opinion) much trickier to use volatile correctly.

Comment: Agree with Mat. Or use an AtomicBoolean, which is even easier IMO.

Answer (score 6):

Use the built-in interrupt mechanism of threads instead of a field

```
public class SomeThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(!isInterrupted()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

From another thread, call `interrupt()` on the thread in order to shut it down. This has the added advantage that it will work even if your thread is waiting on a monitor.

Comment: Ah, thanks. This thread stuff is kind of new to me. I'm more used to pthreads and semaphores. Java makes it too easy, haha.

Comment: This is a better answer and should be accepted one!